# Change IP and/or port for gRPC client

Tags: c++, qt, grpc, qthread

I use C++ gRPC client in unary mode. I use `CompletionQueue` (`cq`), create loop with `cq->Next()` check in a separate thread (`QThread::create()`). I can interrupt this loop via `cq->Shutdown()` and then stop the thread. But what should I do in order to reset the whole stuff for new IP and/or port? I mean channel, stub, completion queue handling. Is completion queue instance reusable after shutdown?

```
const auto& channel = grpc::CreateChannel(
    ip_port,
    grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());
m_stub = Some_service::NewStub(channel);
```